# How to save multiple values from input form fields to JS variable?

Tags: php, ajax, session, plupload

I am using plupload to upload image files. My goal is to save the name of the uploaded thumb_nail files to a session, in case user leaves page or an submit error happens.

Plupload creates file_names in this manner:

```
<div id="files">
    <input type="hidden" id="p1adsfucka1h0p1s0624cauu623" name="files[]" value="p1adsfucka1h0p1s0624cauu623.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" id="p1adsfucka1h0p1s0624cauu624" name="files[]" value="p1adsfucka1h0p1s0624cauu623.jpg">
</div>
```

from plupload functions I want to call this function:

```
function autosave_form_cl(session_name){
    console.log($("input[name=files").val() + $('#title').val());
    $.post("/act_autosave_formdata.php", { 
          session_name:session_name,
          cellphone:    $('#cellphone').val(),
          files:        $("input[name=files").val()
    } );    
}
```

This returns an `undefined` for the value of the file fields. How could I access and save those names? Submitting and saving the values to a session works by accessing `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect all `[name=files]` first then pass it to your `$.post`.

I assume what's inside `<div id="files">` is all inputs with `[name=files]`

```
function autosave_form_cl(session_name){
    //console.log($("input[name=files]").val() + $('#title').val());
    files = [];
    $('div#id').find('input').each(function(i,inp){
        files.push($(inp).val());
    });
    console.log(files);
    $.post("/act_autosave_formdata.php", { 
        session_name:session_name,
        cellphone:    $('#cellphone').val(),
        files:        files
    } );    
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: The inputs are all named "files[]" inside div with id="files". Did not work unfortunately. Do not get any names into the console:   files = [];
    $('div#id').find('input').each(function(i,inp){
        files.push(inp.val());
    });
 console.log('files: ' + files);

Comment: @merlin can you try to `console.log(files);` after the `.each()`.

Comment: I forgot to change div#id to div#files. Now it will enter the loop, but I do get: Uncaught TypeError: inp.val is not a function

Comment: @merlin no problem. glad i helped. :)